# Something was sold by/from

Tags: prepositions

I want to say someone bought something from someone else

And I want to put it this way

**1 edition was sold from/by John to Jenna each for 1 dollar**

Which should I use, *from* or *by*?

Comment: You buy an item FROM someone, e.g "Jen bought a new laptop from John"

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah i know. What if I want to put this sentence differently. A new laptop was sold by/from john to jen. By or from?

Comment: In passive constructions you use "by" "The painting was auctioned BY Sotheby's" and *The 500-year-old drawing **was sold/bought by** Mr. Branzino.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you <3

Comment: I don't think many native speakers would particularly notice the choice of the less common preposition in *local produce is sold **by / from** the village shop*. Granted,  ***from*** there more strongly implies that whoever grew the vegetables receives most/all of the proceeds *after* they're bought, whereas ***by*** implies the shopkeeper already paid the grower(s) when they delivered their produce. But these are just small nuances that might not apply anyway. On the other hand, no native speaker would ever accept ***each for 1 dollar*** here - it has to be ***for 1 dollar each***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you so much

Comment: One edition, not: 1 edition. Start the sentence with the number written out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the passive construction "by" sounds better than "from".
- "for 1 dollar each" sounds better than "each for 1 dollar"

Which leads to

"1 edition was sold by John to Jenna for 1 dollar each"

In ordinary English prose, you don't include "each" when there's one item. So,

"1 edition was sold by John to Jenna for 1 dollar"

Going further, you might consider replacing the digits with a full word.

"An/One edition was sold by John to Jenna for a/one dollar."